# Saving custom fields data from pdp page

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to save custom fields data to database but its not working below is my code

**events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
            <observer name="quote_submit_before" instance="Envision\Ecomm\Observer\QuoteSubmitBefore" />
        </event>
```

**QuoteSubmitBefore.php**

```
use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
class QuoteSubmitBefore  implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       $quote = $observer->getQuote();
       $order = $observer->getOrder();

        $order->setData('subscription_type', $quote->getData('subscription_type'));      
    }
}
```

i have added **subscription_type** fields in **quote** and **sales_order** table.
please let me know what am i missing here.

Comment: First: i am not sure, if order exists at that point, your observer is called. 
Second: Have you tried to run 
   $order->save(); 
?

Comment: yes i have tried that but its not working

Comment: From where you saved data of 'subscription_type' in quote table? Have you checked that custom field value in "Quote table" ?